# Umlaute in Namen ins lateinische Alphabet übertragen

Tags: umlaut

Als Besitzer eines Umlauts (`ü`) im Namen lernt man recht schnell, dass dieses auf Dokumenten oder in Computersoftware oder auch nur im Kreuzworträtsel in ein `ue` gewandelt wird, gleichermaßen mit `ä`und `ö`.

Nun ist mir bei einer finnisch-schwedischen Firma aufgefallen, dass der Username nicht auf diese Weise umgesetzt wurde, sondern einfach durch Weglassen der Punkte, also aus dem `ü` wurde ein `u`. Auf interessierte Nachfrage wurde mir gesagt, dass bei z.B. den schwedischen Usern dies genauso gemacht würde, also aus z.B. einem `å` ein `a` wird oder bei z.B. französischen Usern die Akzente entfernt würden.

War das einfach zufällig eine Sitte dieser Firma oder haben wir im Deutschen mit der Umschreibung mittels `e` eine Besonderheit bei den Nicht-Standard-Latein-Zeichen?

Comment: Diese Frage ist m. E. off-topic, da sie keiner Kenntnisse über die deutsche Sprache bedarf, sodern über andere Sprachen.

Comment: (Vermutlich wäre die Frage aber gut auf [Linguistics](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/) aufgehoben. Die Geschichte dieser Praxis im Deutschen hingegen wäre eine Frage für diese Seite.) Die Dekorationen von Standardbuchstaben nennt man übrigens [diakritische Zeichen](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diakritisches_Zeichen).

Comment: Das Finnische verwendet doch gar kein "ü"? Dieses Weglassen der Dekoration ändert doch aber den Laut, damit das Wort und ggf. dessen Bedeutung. Von Vokalharmonie ganz zu schweigen ;) Davon abgesehen ist m.E. die Umschreibung mit dem "e", wie wir sie heute verwenden, der eigentliche historische Ursprung der Umlautpunkte.

Comment: Englische Wikipedia: In the Nordic countries, the vowel sound [æ] was originally written as "Æ" when Christianisation caused the former Vikings to replace the Runic alphabet with the Latin alphabet around A.D. 1100. The letter Ä arose in German and later in Swedish from originally writing the E in AE on top of the A, which with time became simplified as two dots. In the Icelandic, Faroese, Danish and Norwegian alphabets, "Æ" is still used instead of Ä.

Comment: Das ist keine Sprachfrage, sondern eine der Technik. Im Duden wird man kaum Vorschriften finden, wie ein ö zu handhaben ist - ich habe auch schon a: o: u: und so weiter gefunden. Außerdem bitte ich den Begriff "Standardalphabet" zu erläutern. Wessen Standard? International? IBM? Einwohnermeldeamt? Mein Standardalphabet enthält Umlaute und scharfes S.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about writing conventions of different languages.

Comment: @userunknown IBM-Technik? Es ist schon eine Sprachfrage, nur muss man, um sie zu beantworten, mehrerer Sprachen Orthographie miteinbeziehen. Ginge es nur um's Deutsche, wäre es wohl unter [tag:orthography] on-topic.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: Danke für den Hinweis wie diese bezeichnet werden, danach hatte ich gesucht.

Comment: @userunknown: Wie würdest du denn das Alphabet von A - Z stattdessen bezeichnen? Lateinisches Alphabet? Mit IBM hat das nichts zu tun, auch wenn man im IT Bereich von 7bit ASCII sprechen könnte.

Comment: @Grantwalzer: It was obvious that off-topic comments would arise - but my question just described, what I experienced with other languages, but wanted to know what difference or speciality there may be in my language if any.

Comment: @Geziefer: »[I] wanted to know what difference or speciality there may be in my language if any.« – Die Frage, die Du gestellt hast, beinhaltet aber nur das Ob (bzw. *if any*), nicht das Warum (bzw. *what difference*). Letzteres wäre wie gesagt eine Frage für diese Seite; Ersteres nicht.

Comment: Nebenbei: Der bevorzugte Notbehelf für *å* in skandinavischen Sprachen scheint *aa* zu sein und nicht *a* ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Å#International_transcription)).

Comment: As far as software is concerned, just stripping off all accents is the easiest method, instead of having to deal with local conventions. See eg. [unidecode](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Unidecode/), which turns ä into a. Also, English is common in software/programming, and in English you say `uberhuman` and `doppelganger`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Die Umschreibung mittels `e` ist eine Besonderheit. Tatsächlich sind `ä`, `ö` und `ü` völlig eigenständige Buchstaben. Sie entstanden früher aus den Digraphen `ae`, `oe` und `ue`, indem

1. das `e` in gebrochener Schreibschrift geschrieben wurde
2. das `e` diakritisch über den vorausgehenden Vokal geschrieben wurde
3. das Gebrochene-Schreibschrift-`e` unsauber geschrieben wurde, sodass nur die vertikalen Striche übrig bleiben
4. diese vertikalen Strich zu Punkten verkürzt wurden.

Da sie aber deutlich unterschiedliche Grapheme und Phoneme haben und bedeutungsrelevant sind, sind es von den Vokalen `a`, `o` und `u` unabhängige Buchstaben.

Es gibt also keinerlei Rechtfertigung, in nicht-EDV-Kontexten, also z. B. gedruckten Lexika, Telefonbüchern oder reinen Versalientexten die Umwandlung vorzunehmen. Eine Umwandlung `ä`→`a`, `ö`→`o`, `ü`→`u` wäre allerdings genauso ungerechtfertigt.

In EDV-Kontexten ist eine Umwandlung dann gerechtfertigt, wenn ein Text [ASCII](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Standard_Code_for_Information_Interchange)-kompatibel sein soll. In solchen Fällen sind aber auch wieder beide Umwandlungen nicht angebracht, weil sie nicht injektiv sind. Eine Umwandlung gemäß Unicode-Codepoints wie `ä`→`u+00c4` wäre in den meisten Fällen angebrachter.

Comment: Das beantwortet irgendwie eine andere Frage als gestellt (aber anscheinend ist sich der Fragesteller selbst unsicher, was er eigentlich möchte). Außerdem solltest Du *Sütterlin* durch *gebrochene Schreibschrift* ersetzen, denn als die Sütterlin 1911 entstand, waren die Umlaute schon längst entstanden.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: Interessant, dass ich nicht sicher bin, was ich will ;-)

Comment: Das Argument mit den eigenständigen Buchstaben ist in meinen Augen ein gutes, da es erklärt, warum wir nicht einfach die Punkte weglassen können. Interessant wäre noch, ob das eben für diakritische Zeichen anderer Sprachen auch gilt oder sie hier z.B. eher eine Ausschmückung oder Präzisierung darstellen, die man auch weglassen könnte - womit wiederum meine Frage beantwortet wäre, ob unsere Umlaute hier anders positioniert sind.

Comment: @Geziefer Ich habe die Frage ausschließlich aus Sicht der deutschen Sprache beantwortet. Bezüglich anderer Sprachen müsstest do woanders fragen.